# How do I pass Javascript variable to <jsp:setProperty> and JSTL?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

How do I pass Javascript variable to  and JSTL?

```
<script>

    var name = "john";  

    <jsp:setProperty name="emp" property="firstName" value=" "/>   // How do I set javascript variable(name) value here ?

    <c:set var="firstName" value=""/>  // How do I set javascript variable (name) value here ?     

  </script>
```

Comment: How were the answers on your two previous questions regarding the subject insufficient? You didn't update/comment anything in those questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send it as a request parameter. One of the ways is populating a hidden input field.

```
<script>document.getElementById('firstName').value = 'john';</script>
<input type="hidden" id="firstName" name="firstName">
```

This way you can get it in the server side as request parameter when the form is been submitted.

```
<jsp:setProperty name="emp" property="firstName" value="${param.firstName}" />
```

An alternative way is using Ajax, but that's a completely new story/answer at its own.

#### See also:

- [Communication between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)
- [Your previous question regarding the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288032/how-do-i-assign-hidden-value-to-jstl-variable)
- [Your other previous question regarding the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript)

<sub>If you can't seem to find your previously asked questions back, head to your [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91485/thomman)!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't send data from JavaScript to JSTL that way. Because the JSTL tags are handled serverside, so the `<jsp:>` tags will be parsed on the server and replaced by HTML. So the `<jsp:>` tags won't be a part of the response that is sent back to the client; it will consist only of HTML/text. Therefore you can't access the `<jsp:>` tags from JavaScript, because they won't exist in the document.

Edit: sorry, the `<jsp:>` tags wasn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var name = "<jsp:getProperty name="emp" property="firstName" />";
</script>
```

The JSP code executes before the JavaScript so by the time the JavaScript gets processed the  tag will be replaced with the contents of emp.firstName.

Comment: JSTL Version:

<script>
var name = "<c:out value="${emp.firstName}"/>";
</script>

Comment: He's asking how to pass data from JavaScript to JSTL, not the other way around.