# how to assign a select box value to jstl variable after selecting in same jsp?

Tags: spring, jsp

I am trying to

```
 <select>   
 <option value="">-select-</option>     
 <c:forEach items="${documents}" var="doc">         
    <option value="${doc.getId()}">${doc.getName()}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

This Selected value to assign a new variable like `id`

```
<c:set var='id' value=''/>
```

Comment: Do it using javascript/jQuery by adding `onChange` method inside the select tag and set the selected value to respective variable/element

Comment: can you give an sample code for that

Comment: what you want to do with set variable?

Comment: because i want use that for following list which contains that id those records will be displayed otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

In select tag,

```
<select onchange="myMethod();" name="myTag"></select>
```

In Javascript,

```
function myMethod(){
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("myDropDownId").selectedIndex; 
    alert(selectedValue);   //Check value exist
    document.getElementById("newElem").value = selectedValue; //assign value
}
```

Comment: is this newElem is new jstl variable?

Comment: Name of the element going to hold the selected value. Check this link for detailed explanation [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Quiet easy still, check my answer which was updated now

Comment: bro here i attached my mail id pls send ur number i will call u now borusmartin1122@gmail.com

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515025/how-do-i-pass-javascript-variable-to-jspsetproperty-and-jstl#3515177) too, where you can set the javascript value to `c:set` variable.