# assigning input tag value to a java variable not working

Tags: java, jsp

I know it is a very classic question, but I don't know why this doesnt work for me!!!

```
<input  id="code" value="45" type="hidden"  name="code" >

<%=request.getParameter("code") %>
```

the java tag is supposed to show me 45, but it shows null

Comment: what does the link between "code" and "codeMaint" ?

Comment: post all your code

Comment: oh it's my fault when I paste it, it is code, not codeMaint.

Comment: @Abdelhak this is my problem, I want to pass the value of my input to java, what other code you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass Javascript variable to <jsp:setProperty> and JSTL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515025/how-do-i-pass-javascript-variable-to-jspsetproperty-and-jstl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsp code will execute in your container and at that time the code value will be null.

And the below code prints non null when the incoming request(get/post) contains code parameter in it

```
<%=request.getParameter("code") %>
```

So to make it print 45 append this `your.jsp?code=45` at end of url then it will print 45 in the page

Answer (score 0):

You need html form tag to send the parameters.
Ex:

```
 <form>
   <input id="code" value="45" type="hidden" name="code">
   <%=request.getParameter("code") %>
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
```